# remove specific set of lines with bash script

Tags: bash, text, replace

Hi I came from a lot of threads to acomplish this task but neither works for me. I have a large amount of files that looks likes this:

```
{

    ... 

    frontAndBack
    {
        type            empty;
        inGroups        1 ( empty );
        nFaces          2428620;
        startFace       2264091;
    }

    frontAndBack
    {
        type            empty;
    }

}
```

and I want to remove the lines that contains this part:

```
    frontAndBack
    {
        type            empty;
    }
```

i try this:

```
sed -zi.bak 's/"    frontAndBack\n    {\n        type            empty;\n    }"//g' boundary
```

but didn't work. any help with this?

Comment: `perl -0777 -p -e 's/\s*frontAndBack\s*{\s*type\s*empty;\s*}//g' input`

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks, put it as an answer tu give you the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-line matching in `sed` is ... painful.  But `perl` is great at this sort of thing:

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's/\s*frontAndBack\s*{\s*type\s*empty;\s*}//g' input-path
```